# What are the environment settings in Apache Pig and Hadoop Connection to run tutorial scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run the pig tutorial scripts in Ubuntu for two days, however I can not manage to make pig connect to hadoop file system. It is still saying: " Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///"

In fact, hadoop and pig are both working and I can use them, also pig script under pig installation can connect to the hadoop. 
"Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:54310"
My hadoop directory is under /home/hadoop/Cluster, pig installation is under /usr/share/pig, pig tutorial is home/hadoop/pig and hadoop installation is /home/someuser/hadoop .

I have tried almost every solution in the web, but I still need some help. Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start pig as the following:

```
java -cp /usr/share/pig/pig-0.7.0-core.jar:/home/hadoop/Cluster/conf/ org.apache.pig.Main
```

Where the `/home/hadoop/Cluster/conf/` is the Hadoop configuration directory.

BTW I think it's easier to use [Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop](http://www.cloudera.com/hadoop/) instead of installing your own.

Comment: thanks very much, this is exactly what I found out by my empirical studies.

Comment: @miette: What did you find out? That's how you start pig or that it really is simpler to use Cloudera?

Comment: Never-mind I got pig running with that line. Thanks KARASZI +1